# import db and users from mysql 5

Tags: mysql, users, export

There's a working Mysql 5 database that I want to import into a MariaDB on another machine, including tables, data, users and privileges.
Is There a pretty simple way to do that? I'm not so expert in managing databases, I usually dump data using mysqldump.
Thanks a lot for help!
Regards

Remigio

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `mysqldum` in this case?

Comment: I was not able to do that, could you please give me an example?

Comment: You yourself said: "I usually dump data using mysqldump"; what prevents you from doing so this time?

Comment: Yea, I use mysqldump to backup data, but I would export (and then import in the new machine) users and related privileges. Is it possible?  Thanks

Comment: There's not enough info to give you suggestions. What MariaDB version will you restore the data to? What exact MySQL version are you taking the data from? Does the existing MariaDB instance have data? Are there any similar tables, schemas that may conflict during the restore? Any existing users with similar names on both servers?